# What does pg_resetxlog do? And how does it work?

Tags: postgresql, pg

I have looked at the postgres documentation and the synopsis below is given:

```
pg_resetxlog [-f] [-n] [-ooid ] [-x xid ] [-e xid_epoch ] [-m mxid ] [-O mxoff ] [-l timelineid,fileid,seg ] datadir
```

But at no point in the documentation do they explain what the datadir is.
Is it the `%postgres-path%/9.0/data` or could it be `%postgres-path%/9.0/data/pgxlog` ?

Also, if I want to change my xlog directory, can I simply move the items in my current `pg_xlog` directory and run the command to point to another directory? (Assume my current pg_xlog directory is in `/data1/postgres/data/pg_xlog` AND the directory I want it the logs to go to is: `/data2/pg_xlog`)

Would the following command achieve what I've just described?

```
mv /data1/postgres/data/pg_xlog /data2/pg_xlog
pg_resetxlog /data2
```

Answer (score 6):

[`pg_resetxlog`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgresetxlog.html) is a tool of last resort for getting your database running again after:

- You deleted files you shouldn't have from `pg_xlog`;
- You restored a file system level backup that omitted the `pg_xlog` directory due to a backup system configuration mistake (this happens more than you'd think, people think  "it has log in the name so it must be unimportant; I'll leave it out of the backups").
- File-system corruption due to a hardware fault or hard drive failure damaged your data directory; or potentially even
- a PostgreSQL bug or operating system bug damaged the write-ahead logs (exceedingly rare).

As the manual says:

> pg_resetxlog clears the write-ahead log (WAL) [...]. This
>   function is sometimes needed if these files have become corrupted. It
>   should be used only as a last resort, when the server will not start
>   due to such corruption.

**Do not run `pg_resetxlog` unless you know exactly what you are doing and why**. If you are unsure, ask on the [pgsql-general mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/) or on https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

**`pg_resetxlog` may corrupt your database**, as the documentation warns. If you have to use it, you should `REINDEX`, dump your database(s), re-initdb, and reload your databases. Do not just continue using the damaged cluster. As per the documentation:

> After running this command, it should be possible to start the server,
>   but bear in mind that the database might contain inconsistent data due
>   to partially-committed transactions. You should immediately dump your
>   data, run initdb, and reload. After reload, check for inconsistencies
>   and repair as needed.

If you simply want to move your write-ahead log directory to another location, you should:

- Stop PostgreSQL
- Move `pg_xlog`
- Add a symbolic link from the old location to the new location
- Start PostgreSQL

Or, as the [documentation says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-internals.html):

> It is advantageous if the log is located on a different disk from the
>   main database files. This can be achieved by moving the pg_xlog
>   directory to another location (while the server is shut down, of
>   course) and creating a symbolic link from the original location in the
>   main data directory to the new location.

If PostgreSQL fails to start, you've done something wrong. Do not use `pg_resetxlog` to "fix" it. Undo your changes and work out what you did wrong.

Comment: You seem to be saying "never use pg_resetxlog", but I just used it and it fixed my problem.

Comment: @Fuser97381 I'm saying it should be an absolute last resort and that you should dump, re-initdb and reload if you are forced to use it. It is not a normal operation, it is an emergency recovery tool with serious vonsequences.

Answer (score 2):

Move the contents of your pg_xlog directory to the desired location like '/home/foo/pg_xlog'

```
mv pg_xlog/* /home/foo/pg_xlog
```

Delete the pg_xlog directory

```
rm -rf pg_xlog
```

Create a soft-link of pg_xlog

```
ln -s /home/foo/pg_xlog pg_xlog
```

Verify the link

```
ls -lrt pg_xlog
```

Note: pg_resetxlog is not the right tool to move the pg_xlog please read

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgresetxlog.html

Answer (score 1):

The data directory corresponds to the `data_directory` entry in the postgresql.conf file, or the `PGDATA` environment variable, and it can also be queried live in SQL with the `SHOW data_directory` statement. It does not point to the `pg_xlog` directory, but one level above.

To change the location of the WAL files, the PG server must be shut down, the `pg_xlog` directory and its contents moved to the new location, a symbolic link should be created from the old location to the new location, and the server restarted. `pg_resetxlog` should not be used for this, as it may suppress the latest transactions (this tool is typically used in crash recovery situations when all else fails).

Answer (score 0):

You should never manually touch the WAL files, that is perfectly clear.

If there is dangling files in the `pg_xlog` directory, that is, there are is file which ends with `.done*` in the sub-folder `archive_status` which need to be cleaned up manually, that can be accomplished with the sql command

```
CHECKPOINT;
```

which forces a transaction checkpoint which includes cleaning up the WAL segment files.

See [documentation for 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-checkpoint.html) but exists in all current versions of Postgresql.