# dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR: checkpoint request failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, macos, postgresql

I only know the basics of using postgres db and have been using it for about a year without any major problems I couldn't get through with the docs or existing stackoverflow questions.

But now I have a problem where I keep getting the following error on my pg db on my mac. I tried to install an updated postgres using brew which installed successful, but I think in the process I created another problem. The error is when trying to start the db:

```
LOG:  database system shutdown was interrupted; last known up at 2015-10-04 11:04:08 EDT
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  redo starts at 0/6000090
LOG:  record with zero length at 0/6001990
LOG:  redo done at 0/6001960
LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2015-10-04 10:56:33.121103-04
FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
LOG:  startup process (PID 12905) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

So I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897429/what-does-pg-resetxlog-do-and-how-does-it-work) for using pg_resetxlog and then procceeded to try and "REINDEX, dump your database(s), re-initdb, and reload your databases" Per pg documentation for 9.4 with no successful results. Im just going in circles.

I can start over with the db but I'm unable to drop it and start over. If I run dropdb dbname I get

```
dropdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

But I can't start the db because after running

```
pg_resetxlog -f /usr/local/var/postgres
```

And getting back "Transaction log reset" I run

```
pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

And get

```
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
server starting
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 13114) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

So I ran

```
ps auxwww | grep postgres
```

And got

```
Travis          13127   0.0  0.0  2432772    660 s000  S+   11:24AM   0:00.00 grep postgres
Travis          13120   0.0  0.0  2468112    604   ??  Ss   11:21AM   0:00.00 postgres: stats collector process       
Travis          13119   0.0  0.0  2604776   1444   ??  Ss   11:21AM   0:00.00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process       
Travis          13118   0.0  0.0  2604776    732   ??  Ss   11:21AM   0:00.00 postgres: wal writer process       
Travis          13117   0.0  0.0  2612968   1776   ??  Ss   11:21AM   0:00.05 postgres: writer process       
Travis          13116   0.0  0.0  2604776    756   ??  Ss   11:21AM   0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process       
Travis          13114   0.0  0.2  2604776  14576   ??  S    11:21AM   0:00.02 /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

So I ran

```
kill 13114
```

Then

```
ps auxwww | grep postgres
```

And got

```
Travis          13139   0.0  0.0  2432772    652 s000  S+   11:25AM   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

Of course at this point if I try to start the db again I go in the same circle.

Now if I run

```
pg_resetxlog -f /usr/local/var/postgres
```

followed by

```
psql template1
```

And try to drop the db nothing happens.

It's a db for a rails project. So if I run

```
rake db:drop
```

I get another

```
PG::InternalError: ERROR:  checkpoint request failed
```

It also says there is a hint in the server log which I checked with

live:

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

Or:

```
tail /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

And get

```
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
ERROR:  could not open directory "pg_logical/snapshots": No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure how to fix that or why it dosent exist anymore in the first place. Search results returned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972351/what-is-the-purpose-of-pg-logical-directory-inside-postgresql-data) but there was no solution showing the full path for manually creating the directory

At this point I'm so confused I think I'm making things worse.

I checked other db on my system and see I have the same problem for all databases on my machine now. Plus I always have 1 grep postgres pid running that i can't stop with kill 13498 or by restarting my mac.

How do i fix this without loosing all databases on my machine?

Brew info postgres shows:

```
postgresql: stable 9.4.4 (bottled), devel 9.5alpha2
Object-relational database system
https://www.postgresql.org/
Conflicts with: postgres-xc
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1_1 (2996 files, 40M)
  Poured from bottle
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.4 (3014 files, 40M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/postgresql.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔, readline ✔
==> Options
--32-bit
    Build 32-bit only
--with-dtrace
    Build with DTrace support
--with-python
    Build with python support
--without-perl
    Build without Perl support
--without-tcl
    Build without Tcl support
--devel
    Install development version 9.5alpha2
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.4) of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/upgrading.html

To have launchd start postgresql at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load postgresql now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I'm running yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: Are you using BDR? Or PostgreSQL 9.5 beta? Either way, Mac OS X seems to like to randomly delete empty directories, which the database system doesn't like much.

Comment: Hey Craig, I'm using postgresql: stable 9.4.4 (bottled), devel 9.5alpha2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a few more hours of research I got things working again without loosing any of my databases.

From my other mac I found where the directory should be created that the user referenced in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972351/what-is-the-purpose-of-pg-logical-directory-inside-postgresql-data) post that needed to be created. I also created the other two missing directories:

```
mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical
mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical/mappings
mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical/snapshots
```

Next I ran the following for good measure

```
brew update
```

and

```
brew doctor
```

Then I installed brew services ([info docs](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services) and [article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew) )

```
brew tap homebrew/services
```

Next i ran the following which i derived from hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930167/postgresql-server-wont-stop/24135897#24135897) because in the process of troubleshooting/trial and error the "pg_resetxlog -f /usr/local/var/postgres" command started throwing errors.

```
brew services stop postgresql
```

Then I tried my usual

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

And everything started working normally. Since brew services is installed now I can start the db with:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

I'm still not sure why restarting my mac didn't help after creating the directories. And I'm also not sure why/how/when those directories were removed. And I'm not sure what really created the problems to start with. But after doing what I've listed, everything is working.

Comment: Mac OS X seems to have the nasty habit of deleting empty directories when it feels like it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have faced below error while deleting the database:

> Error: **checkpoint request failed**

Need to restart the database and you can try to delete database.

sucessfully delete database.

Answer (score 1):

If the disk space is full, you will not be able to drop any database and you will consistently get the ***'Error: checkpoint request failed'*** message.

To manually delete the database follow these steps:
 1. Shutdown Postgres (note that Postgres won't restart until you free up disk space)
 2. Delete the database data directory (dddd) in /var/lib/postgresql/9.x/main/base/dddd
 3. Restart Postgres (it should restart now that you have freed up space)
 4. Execute 'drop database db_name' through psql console (to finish the cleanup)